# Get Records basis on Month - mysql

Tags: mysql

## Fiddle

**Query,**

```
SELECT
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=1,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '1',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=2,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '2',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=3,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '3',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=4,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '4',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=5,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '5',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=6,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '6',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=7,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '7',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=8,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '8',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=9,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '9',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=10,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '10',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=11,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '11',
  IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=12,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '12'
FROM `tyr_profile_view` p
WHERE p.user_id != '59'
    AND p.`user_id` != 0
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

**Record show like this,**

[image]

OUTPUT of above query

```
|  1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|----|----|
| 18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

Above data clear you, what is my problem, but if still you are not understand my question Please feel free to ask me.

**P.S. I want a proper way which show exactly result. This is working but give not proper result.**

Comment: Refresh your page, may be some issue on loading. I open in another browser without logged in , it is working.

Comment: Can you display the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it like this

## Fiddle

Query

```
SELECT
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=1, 1, NULL)) AS '1',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=2, 1, NULL)) AS '2',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=3, 1, NULL)) AS '3',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=4, 1, NULL)) AS '4',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=5, 1, NULL)) AS '5',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=6, 1, NULL)) AS '6',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=7, 1, NULL)) AS '7',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=8, 1, NULL)) AS '8',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=9, 1, NULL)) AS '9',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=10, 1, NULL)) AS '10',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=11, 1, NULL)) AS '11',
    COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=12, 1, NULL)) AS '12'
FROM `tyr_profile_view` p
WHERE p.user_id != '59'
    AND p.`user_id` != 0
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Output

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|----|----|
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 6 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

Note : Created this query as Alma Do Suggested

Exactly required:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because you're selecting `COUNT` for each record. It is not the way how `IF` works. Instead, you should do aggregation in outer scope, so instead of:

```
IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=1,COUNT(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))),0) AS '1'
```

do

```
COUNT(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=1, 1, NULL)) AS '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something as

```
SELECT
sum(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=1,1,0)) AS '1',
sum(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=2,1,0)) AS '2',
sum(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=3,1,0)) AS '3',
sum(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=4,1,0)) AS '4',
sum(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=5,1,0)) AS '5',
sum(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=6,1,0)) AS '6',
..........................
FROM `tyr_profile_view` p
WHERE p.user_id != '59'
    AND p.`user_id` != 0
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

So it will get the sum() by checking the month value in if condition

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51b620/21)**

Answer (score 1):

Try with `SUM` Combined `IF`

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=1, 1, 0)) AS 'January',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=2, 1, 0)) AS 'Feburary',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=3, 1, 0)) AS 'March',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=4, 1, 0)) AS 'April',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=5, 1, 0)) AS 'May',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=6, 1, 0)) AS 'June',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=7, 1, 0)) AS 'July',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=8, 1, 0)) AS 'Augest',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=9, 1, 0)) AS 'September',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=10, 1, 0)) AS 'October',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=11, 1, 0)) AS 'November',
  SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp))=12, 1, 0)) AS 'December'
FROM `tyr_profile_view` p
WHERE p.user_id != '59'
    AND p.`user_id` != 0
    AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(p.created_timestamp)) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

---

*Output:*

---

```
JANUARY FEBURARY    MARCH   APRIL   MAY JUNE    JULY    AUGEST  SEPTEMBER   OCTOBER NOVEMBER    DECEMBER
1       0           0       3       6   8       0       0       0           0        0           0
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51b620/25)**

Comment: If I use count, there is no difference, so why you use sum? Please share .